# Using AutoHotkey, how to send a series of key combinations, by pressing one key

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, autohotkey

I want to send ctrl+End, ctrl+shift+home, ctrl+c when I press w, I am using this combination to copy all the text (ctrl+a ctrl+c does not work in the application I am using).  This script is not working.

```
w::Send, ^{End}^{Shift}{Home}^c
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sending `{Shift}` sends Shift as a keypress, not a modifier. You need to use the `+` character instead.

Try this:

```
w:: Send, ^{End}^+{Home}^c
```

Comment: Thanks tvStatic, this one worked
w:: Send, ^{End}^+{Home}^c